# Why can't I catch Capybara::ElementNotFound in the to_raise matcher?

Tags: rspec, capybara

```
pry#<> expect(find("#recipients")).to raise_error(Capybara::ElementNotFound)
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible css "#recipients"
```

I know it's hard and potentially error prone to test that certain elements are "not" found, but I feel confident my use case is a good one.

I'm trying to make a #dont_find matcher...

Comment: The answer by Alex D is correct but why not just do `expect(page).not_to have_css('#recipients')` or `expect(page).to have_no_css('#receipients')` which are actual expectations rather than a '#dont_find` method, or potentially a custom selector and/or helper methods `have_recipients`, etc - if you're looking to get more complicated.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but there is a very subtle, yet extremely important difference between find and have_css. Find actually makes sure that the selector is "visible", whereas have_css doesn't. In my case the selector is actually on the page, but is hidden. I tried an implementation like this initially but it didn't work. Regrettably this isn't obvious from the documentation for #find. The exception shows it's looking for 'visible' elements: Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible css "abc"

Comment: You're wrong about that --  both `find` and `have_css` check visibility  by default.  If you have a case where it's not that would be a serious bug and you should file an issue on the Capybara project.

Comment: Just to clarify why I know I'm right on that - I am the current author of Capybara.  So if you do have a case where `have_css` isn't verifying visibility please do file an issue on Capybara so I can confirm and fix.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't has_css (has_css ?) that I used, but the first implementation I used returned true when the selector was on the page, visible or not.

Comment: Without knowing what you were doing it's impossible to say, but the only way any of Capybaras methods would return true for both visible and non-visible elements is if `visible: false` or `visible: :all` was specified  (or `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements` was changed from its default, but that would affect `find` too).  Either way you're generally going to have much better results using Capybara matchers (have_...)  and, if needed, combining them with `.and`/`.or` than trying to write your own matcher.  If you want to discuss it more email me or contact me on the Capybara gitter page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to pass `find('#recipients')` directly to `expect`, but this doesn't work, because `find` raises an exception and thus `expect` is never even called. You should be passing a block instead, like so:

```
expect { find('#recipients') }.to raise_error(Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Comment: If you want to assert if an element exist it's a better solution use a capybara matcher like has_css? with an rspec expectation i think
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_css%3F-instance_method
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

Comment: @bott That is a good point. I just copied the OP's code and fixed his bug, but didn't think about writing the assertion in a totally different way. You could post another answer if you like.